# How to loop forms in one page based on the number of entries

Tags: php

i am doing a crime management web application using php.

The page is like this when run it,it gives a chance to enter Details about the case,then click on submit button it brings another form on the same page.

that Form will ask you to enter the number of accused involved,if lets say for instance you have two accused,it will bring another form on the same page that will allow you to enter personal data bout accused number one ...then click on submit button it bring you another form that asks you to enter the number of crimes accused number one has committed...if lets say again he committed 3 crimes then it brings a select form which allows you to select the crime and submit 3 times.

After the third entry it will go back again and give you a form to enter personal details about accused number two....same process as accused one an when you are done it takes you back to the initial point where it would be ready to enter a new case

i pray its clear....please help

this is my earlier code ...ready to run

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["start"]))
    {
        switch($_SESSION["now"])
        {
            case 0:
                $_SESSION["now"]++;
                echo    " <p style='text-align:center;'><H1> ==Welcom Page, you need to start here==</h1></p>
                        <br><br><br><br>
                        <form action='index.php'  method='post' name='page'>
                        <p h3>Please Enter your max number.... 
                            <input type='number' name='max' style='width:140px;' required='required'/>
                            <input type='submit' name='GO'></p>
                        </form>";
                break;
            case 1:
                if(isset($_POST[max]))
                {
                    $_SESSION["end"]=$_POST[max];
                    echo "<p style='text-align:center;'><H2> Sequence 1</h1></p>
                            <form action='index.php'  method='post' name='page'>
                                value 1: <input type='text' name='x' style='width:140px;'/><br>
                                value 2: <input type='text' name='y' style='width:140px;'/><br>
                                value 3: <input type='text' name='z' style='width:140px;'/><br>
                                <p style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' name='Next'>
                            </form>";
                    $_SESSION["now"]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if($_SESSION["now"]==1)
                    {
                        $_SESSION["now"]=0;
                        header( "Location: index.php");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                    break;
            default:
                if($_SESSION["now"]<=$_SESSION["end"])
                {
                    $x=$_SESSION["now"];
                    $_SESSION["now"]++;
                    echo "<p style='text-align:center;'><H2> Sequence $x</h1></p>
                        <form action='index.php'  method='post' name='page'>
                            value 1: <input type='text' name='x' style='width:140px;'/><br>
                            value 2: <input type='text' name='y' style='width:140px;'/><br>
                            value 3: <input type='text' name='z' style='width:140px;'/><br>
                            <p style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' name='Next'>
                        </form>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<p style='text-align:center;'><H2> Successful, Please refresh the page to restart your sequence ...</h1></p>";
                    session_destroy();
                }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["start"]=true;
        $_SESSION["now"]=0;
        header( "Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you would need to use javascript if you want the page to act dynamic in this way

Comment: Js is your friend ..;)

Comment: I have done using php but it has some probs when i try linking to mysql....it inserts the first part and it doesn't give you the chance to continue with the second accused

Comment: let me try and post that code here

Comment: Please check the initial code i,ve just edited my post ....I have done using php but it has some probs when i try linking to mysql....it inserts the first part and it doesn't give you the chance to continue with the second accused .....@lagbox @ Avinash Babu

Comment: @Mbokodvo2014: The problem with this code is that it is not extensible. If after a while you decide you need to "insert" a state or that there are options where the next state depends, maintaining it will become extremely hard. You better implement a page-oriented finite state machine...

Comment: @CommuSoft: i'm new to php and if its possible i beg you,plz post me something close to what you saying...i'm trying to meet a dealine of my graduation project and that is the only JAM i have.....ma email is sayeed2014@hotmail.com incase anyone would like to email me a php scripted example